# The World of Chess

Tags: society, fantasy-races, chess

Imagine, for a moment, that you wake up on a strange world. Sixty-four sqaures cover your view, alternating in color. You look to your left. A Queen looks back, but this isn't your normal chess Queen. This Queen is a meter and a half tall and almost...alive. You look back at your legs. You have no legs. You are a chess piece, the White King to be exact, and this is your domain. Well, at least if you manage to checkmate the Black pieces on the other side of the board.

My question about this world is what would be the societal structure? I want my pieces to have a feudal-like system with the King and Queen in charge of all the lords(the non-pawn pieces like Knights) which in turn control pawns, but how stable is that really? What prevents pawns from moving backward, Rooks from moving diagonally or Bishops jumping over pieces, if they are sentient and can think for themselves? And most of all, what prevents pieces from exiting the board or betraying their King? With these potential crises in mind, what would the King do to stop their pieces going rampant?

Comment: You are the one who gave thought to the chess pieces in the first place.
So it is something you should at least help us figure out.
I mean this is 100% opinion based until you provide more context.
So you should change to be something more concrete.
Like something to do with the command structure of an army or kingdom or anything that is so very very broad.
This is just so that it does not get closed and we can actually help you with answers.
I mean I can randomly pick reasons like: the king has magical power or entity X decided so or even the king is a sort of hivemind...etc.

Comment: Well actually these are great suggestions! But I will edit it to make it more concrete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

### Psychological nativism / fixed action patterns

[Psychological nativism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_nativism) is the idea that some behaviours aren't learned, but are 'pre-loaded' into a creature's brain. An example would be a herding dog which needs no training to display some level of herding behaviour, or a hunting dog which will 'point' without being trained. Sentient chess pieces with such innate behaviour may take a keen interest in the game being played, anticipate when they will be moved and participate willingly in all legal moves that the king commands them. They will not generally make illegal moves because, for want of better description, it is their 'instinct'. Pieces with poorer chess instincts may be more individualistic and rebel.

Less sentient beings may have innate behavioral sequences hard wired into their neural structure, commonly called [fixed action patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_action_pattern). This is a fixed behaviour that occurs in response to some stimulus. The Wikipedia page lists a couple of examples found in nature. In the chess world a stimulus could be the king commanding a movement, "Queen's Knight up and right," which elicits a fixed and stereotypical response from the knight in question. The pieces' default behaviour would be to stay at rest, only moving on stimulus.

Comment: I did change my question but this is a great thing to point out! In fact most traits seen by animals are in their genetics and not learned.